# Outlook for Mac 2008 & "This message is no longer available on the server"

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, osx-mountain-lion, macbook-pro, imap

I recently helped my client to transfer his mailaccount from a Microsoft Outlook 2003 (POP) box to a new, transfered IMAP account. He moved all the mails that where saved on that Outlook 2003 installation, into the new IMAP account.

After that, he stopped using the old computer and moved to a Macbook, with Outlook for Mac 2008 (14.3.9, 131030). Since then, every day he gets in groups of 5, the following message (This the full source):

```
From: System Administrator <root@localhost>
Subject: message unavailable

This message is no longer available on the server.
```

I've tried figuring out what the cause is of these messages, if any action could be linked to it (for example, deleting messages, or moving messages), but I can't figure out what is causing this.

Is there anyone that knows what (can) cause this behaviour?

Comment: What do you mean by *a new, transferred IMAP account*? Is this a local IMAP account? or a gmail account etc? And if it is local, where is it stored?

Comment: With that I mean it is a new IMAP account, were all the mails from the old POP box were transferred to. The IMAP account is remote, stored on my dedicated mailserver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never encountered such a problem, but one wild guess would be that Outlook is set
to synchronize headers and that the emails no longer exist on the server
when trying to fully download.

This might be because the ISP has moved them to a Junk folder or some other reason.

If Outlook is set to download headers, try to set it to download full messages and see if this helps.

Comment: This makes sense. If changed this option.. I'll await the results :-)